# How to maintain session while navigating a website using Python- 401 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I am trying to write a Python script that logins to a website and navigate to a link post successful login. I am unable to maintain the session when I navigate to other links.

I tried to do it by using Requests import. I am able to login to the website and getting 401 error when I navigate to other page.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "AMITHSR"
PASSWORD = "******"

LOGIN_URL = "https://login.apigee.com/login"
TARGET_URL = "https://apigee.com/organizations/amithsr77-eval/proxies"


def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='X-Uaa-Csrf']/@value")))[0]

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "username": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,
        "X-Uaa-Csrf": authenticity_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=LOGIN_URL))
    print(result)

    page = session_requests.get(TARGET_URL)//401 error is here
    tree2 = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `requests.sessions.Session()` for this task. (My installation's documentation for `requests.session()` says that this is deprecated).

If you use the `Session()` object you can prepare the request and then send it and that *should* allow you to then GET() your target url.